# How to keep all tones in my image between #f5f5f5 and #a0a0a0 automatically?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have some images that I need to put in Black and White, but the tones need to be between #f5f5f5 and #a0a0a0 colors.

And I need to do this in a lot of images, so I need to do this automaticaly, without more edits. How could I do this?

Comment: Levels has a slider at the bottom for output range.... Then record and action and batch

Comment: Use a Gradient Map. You can either use an adjustment layer or use the destructive option in Image > Adjustments. Either option can be turned into an action for easy repeatability.

Comment: Two good suggestions here. For them to work, make sure that your source images spans from black (#000000) to white (#ffffff) before doing the adjustment.